# How to center a row in bootstrap(col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2), that has 4 imgs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried a lot of different solutions: added class center-block to "row", wrap "row" in . I just want to have 4 imges, centered, but instead they are shifted to the left. Please help me, what`s my mistake? thank you.

```
<div class = "row center-block">
    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="tea">
        </a>
            <div class = "desc">1</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt="Посуда">
        </a>
            <div class = "desc">2</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <div class = "desc">3</div>
            </div>

    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=" ">
        </a>
            <div class = "desc">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put up some code. Rows aren't centered, columns can be, and images can be inside a column, but not rows. Code helps us understand what you are thinking

Comment: Here is my code, @Leeish

Comment: So you want the image centered inside each column? Or you want to have the 8 columns (on desktop) centered/evenly spaced?

Comment: col-md-offset-2, col-lg-offset-2, col-xs-offset-0, col-xs-sm-0
on the first div based on your current approach.  Also in your example, col-xs on your divs is missing a dash.  Can also do text-align: center on the images to center them.  or margin: 0 auto;

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistake, @Andrew Ice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want. Note, you only need to specify the smaller size if the larger is the same. You don't need `col-lg-2` since the `col-md-2` cover the `md` side and up. All I added was `col-md-offset-2` which moves that column 2 over. You had 8 columns (2x4) and there are 12 total. So 12-8 = 4. If you want it centered then you want to split that so 4/2 = 2.

```
<div class = "row center-block">
    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="tea">
        </a>
            <div class = "desc">1</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive"  alt="Посуда">
        </a>
            <div class = "desc">2</div>
    </div>

    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive">
        </a>
        <div class = "desc">3</div>
            </div>

    <div class = "col xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-2">
        <a target="_blank" href="tea-003.jpg">
            <img src="tea-003.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=" ">
        </a>
            <div class = "desc">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want them evenly spaced across the entire row at all screen sizes, you'll need to look into flexbox. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you so much for helping such a noobie!

Answer (score 0):

class="img-responsive center-block" add this inside img tag

Comment: Look at the view source of this website: http://lovelylall4id.com/                  The picture on left is centered within column  <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4 text-center"><img src="images/sdf.png" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="image" >